# How to toggle on Order in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am doing sorting in `asc` and `desc`. I want to make logic if User click first time I want to update it with `name asc`, when User click second time I want to update it with `name desc`. It will repeat same manner when ever user click.

**Code**

```
        class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Comment: Repeat means you want to change the sorting order to Asc in the 3rd click?

Comment: @TRomesh , Yes and thanks for comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle based on what you have in the state.

```
getSortedData = () => {
  this.setState({
    sortedData: this.state.sortedData === "name asc" ? "name desc" : "name asc"
  }, () => {
    this.getData();
  });
};
```

So this one will work on the following way:

```js
sortedData = "name asc";
console.log(sortedData);
setInterval(function () {
  sortedData = sortedData === "name asc" ? "name desc" : "name asc";
  console.log(sortedData);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's working . I want more , actually I want to reset state data to initial when User on last page ( Because I am using pagination ) and want to sort in `asc` to `desc` or `desc` to `asc` . For example If user click for `asc` sorting in page ` and user reaced to last page now user want to sort in `desc` so I want to reset the value of state because I am incrementing values of state in every click

Comment: @Andrew Why are you incrementing the values? Sorry, I didn't get that part.

Comment: Actually , I am using loopback filter for pagination . On every click of next I am increamenting the values . but I want if user on page 3 or on last page . If user click for sorting I want to rest values to initial value which I declare in state

Comment: @Andrew Is that server side rendering? Like an API that renders the stuff server side? In that case, will you be able to get the API return the sorted logic? Just wondering that would be better since you have some pagination on it.

Comment: Yes , Actually On every click I am fetching limited data through pagination so that's why I was wondering if I should empty states values

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. I think you can do something like that.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    names: ['Ane', 'Robert', 'Jane'],
    asc: true,
  };
  
  toggleOrder = () => {
    this.setState({
      names: this.state.asc
        ? this.state.names.sort()
        : this.state.names.reverse(),
      asc: !this.state.asc,
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const { names, asc } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={this.toggleOrder}
        >
          {
            asc ? 'des' : 'asc'
          }
        </button>
        <ul>
          {
            names.map(name => (
              <li>{name}</li>
            ))      
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

define `order` in your component state and initialize it with true.

```js
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          order: true, 
          sortedData: ''
        }
       }
       
        getSortedData =() => {
            
            if (this.state.order) {
              this.setState({order: false, sortedData: 'name desc' }, () => {
                this.getData();
              });
            } else {
              this.setState({order: true, sortedData: 'name asc' }, () => {
                this.getData();
              });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sort toggle function sample code with functional component:

```
const [sortable, setSortable] = useState(true);

function handleSort() {
  setSortable(!sortable);
  const sortedData = [...filteredData].sort((a: any, b: any) => {
     return sortable ? (a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1) : (a.title > b.title ? -1 : 1);
  })
  setFilteredData(sortedData);
}

return <button onClick={handleSort}>Sort</button>
```